# Access dash app form input value without callback state

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm developing a dash app and I have a dynamic form group being created from a JSON metadata uploaded by user.
My problem is that I only have the form inputs ids after user uploads, so I can't define at server start the State id for each input in my callback decorator.

```
@self.parent_app.callback(
            Output('output-div', 'children'),
            [Input('button_submit', component_property='n_clicks')],
            [State("form-input-0", "value"),..., State("form-input-n", "value")] # I can't do this
)
```

When the button_submit is pressed I have to access all form data to create an output.

**My question is:**
There is another way to access the input values ​​of my form without using the states in the callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other direct way to access the input values of your form. However, you should be able to achieve what you want via [pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks). Your callback would be something like,

```
from dash.dependencies import ALL

@self.parent_app.callback(
            Output('output-div', 'children'),
            [Input('button_submit', component_property='n_clicks')],
            [State(dict(name="form-input", idx=ALL), "value")])
```

and the dynamically generated form inputs should have ids of the form

```
dict(name="form-input", idx=i)
```

where `i` would typically be an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed!